# Unable to use connect event in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, vue.js, google-chrome-extension

I have `content.js`, `popup.html`, `popup.js`. I am using vue in the chrome extension, for that i used Vue CDN. Its all good. In the `content.js` if i print **document**, it is printing the current tab document(eg: google.com). Now i have a button the chrome extension, on click on that button i want to access the document again(google.com). How can i do that?

**In popup.js**

```
    onClickButton: function() {
          var port = chrome.extension.connect({
           name: "Sample Communication"
          });
          port.postMessage("Hi BackGround");
          port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
              console.log("message recieved" + msg);
          });
    }
```

**In content.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function(port) {
    console.log("Connected .....");
    port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
      console.log("message recieved" + msg);
      port.postMessage("Hi Popup.js");
   });
})
```

The event is not event triggering whats the mistake in here?

Comment: Your content script can access the web page document so IIUC all you need is to use chrome.tabs.connect instead of chrome.extension.connect and specify the tab id which you can get via chrome.tabs.query with active: true and currentWindow:true. See the documentation and examples.

Comment: That's working, perfect thanks...